# Why filtering a cropped image is 4x slower than filtering resized image (both have the same dimensions)

Tags: swift, core-graphics, core-image

I've been trying to wrap my head around this problem with no luck. I have a very simple Swift command-line application which takes one argument - image path to load. It crops the image and filters that image fragment with SepiaTone filter.

It works just fine. It crops the image to 200x200 and filters it with SepiaTone. Now here's the problem that I'm facing - the whole process takes **600ms** on my MacBook Air. Now when I RESIZE (instead of cropping) input image to the same dimensions (200x200) it takes **150ms**.

Why is that? **In both cases I'm filtering an image which is 200x200 in size**. I'm using [this particular image](https://static.pexels.com/photos/4062/landscape-mountains-nature-lake.jpeg) for testing (5966x3978).

**UPDATE:**

It's this particular line of code that takes 4x longer when dealing with cropped image:

```
var ciImage:CIImage = CIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
```

**END OF UPDATE**

Code for cropping (200x200):

```
// parse args and get image path
let args:Array = CommandLine.arguments
let inputFile:String = args[CommandLine.argc - 1]
let inputURL:URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: inputFile)

// load the image from path into NSImage
// and convert NSImage into CGImage
guard
    let nsImage = NSImage(contentsOf: inputURL),
    var cgImage = nsImage.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil)
else {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
}

// CROP THE IMAGE TO 200x200
// THIS IS THE ONLY BLOCK OF CODE THAT IS DIFFERENT
// IN THOSE TWO EXAMPLES
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)

if let croppedImage = cgImage.cropping(to: rect) {
    cgImage = croppedImage
} else {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
}

// END CROPPING



// convert CGImage to CIImage
var ciImage:CIImage = CIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

// initiate SepiaTone
guard
    let sepiaFilter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")
else {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
}

sepiaFilter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
sepiaFilter.setValue(0.5, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)

guard
    let result = sepiaFilter.outputImage
else {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
}

let context:CIContext = CIContext()

// perform filtering in a GPU context
guard
    let output = context.createCGImage(sepiaFilter.outputImage!, from: ciImage.extent)
else {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
}
```

Code for resizing (200x200):

```
// parse args and get image path
let args:Array = CommandLine.arguments
let inputFile:String = args[CommandLine.argc - 1]
let inputURL:URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: inputFile)

// load the image from path into NSImage
// and convert NSImage into CGImage
guard
    let nsImage = NSImage(contentsOf: inputURL),
    var cgImage = nsImage.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil)
else {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
}

// RESIZE THE IMAGE TO 200x200
// THIS IS THE ONLY BLOCK OF CODE THAT IS DIFFERENT
// IN THOSE TWO EXAMPLES
guard let CGcontext = CGContext(data: nil,
                              width: 200,
                              height: 200,
                              bitsPerComponent: cgImage.bitsPerComponent,
                              bytesPerRow: cgImage.bytesPerRow,
                              space: cgImage.colorSpace ?? CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                              bitmapInfo: cgImage.bitmapInfo.rawValue)
else {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
}

CGcontext.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))

if let resizeOutput = CGcontext.makeImage() {
    cgImage = resizeOutput
}

// END RESIZING



// convert CGImage to CIImage
var ciImage:CIImage = CIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

// initiate SepiaTone
guard
    let sepiaFilter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")
else {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
}

sepiaFilter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
sepiaFilter.setValue(0.5, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)

guard
    let result = sepiaFilter.outputImage
else {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
}

let context:CIContext = CIContext()

// perform filtering in a GPU context
guard
    let output = context.createCGImage(sepiaFilter.outputImage!, from: ciImage.extent)
else {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
}
```

Comment: not an answer, but why not use core image cropping instead, so the whole operation can be done in the CI pipeline? You can even create the CIImage straight from the url.

Comment: @jrturton Will try cropping with CI and check what the overall performance is. The question still holds true - why this `CIImage(cgImage: cgImage)` is 4x slower when dealing with cropped image

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "not an answer". It'd be interesting to find out the reason.

Comment: Just checked with `CICrop`. Now the problem is that the original 5966x3978 image has to be loaded directly as CIImage. It takes around 550ms. That's a bit strange because this timing is similar to the timing in my original question

Comment: Have you tried this with multiple different source images, in multiple different image formats?

Answer (score 2):

Its very likely that the cgImage lives in video memory and when you scale the image it actually uses the hardware to write the image to a new area of memory.  When you crop the cgImage the [documentation implies](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgimage/1454683-cropping) that it is just referencing the original image. The line

var ciImage:CIImage = CIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

must be triggering a read (maybe to main memory?), and in the case of your scaled image it can probably just read the whole buffer continuously.  In the case of the cropped image it may be reading it line by line and this could account for the difference, but thats just me guessing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are doing two very different things. In the "slow" version you are **cropping** (as in taking a small CGRect of the original image) and in the "fast" version you are **resizing** (as in reducing the original down to a CGRect).

You can prove this by adding two UIImageViews and adding these lines after each declaration of ciImage:

```
    slowImage.image = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage)
    fastImage.image = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage)
```

Here are two simulator screenshots, with the "slow" image above the "fast" image. The first is with your code where the "slow" CGRect origin is (0,0) and the second is with it adjusted to (2000,2000):

Origin is (0,0)
[image: Origin is (0,0)]
Origin is (2000,2000)
[image: Origin is (2000,2000)]

Knowing this, I can come up with a few things happening on the timing.

I'm including a link to Apple's documentation on the cropping function. It explains that it is doing some CGRect calculations behind the scenes but it doesn't explain **how** it pulls the pixel bits out of the full-sized CG image - I think that's where the real slow down is.

In the end though, it looks like the timing is due to doing two entirely different things.

[CGRect.cropping(to:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgimage/1454683-cropping)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I know what I'm doing with those images, I know how those resized/cropped images look like. What I still don't know is **why** it takes longer to process cropped image.

Comment: I imagine it's in the deepest technicalities of the difference. I believe the OS still must render the 5966x3978 in some type of context in order to pull out the 200x200 subrect, right? That's a lot more CPU/GPU processing than taking that 5966x3978 and simply rending it into a 200x200 context.